# JQuery function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, closures

```
this.slideUpComm = function (){
    $("#Day-events-content p").addClass("hidden").slideUp("fast");
} 
this.showhideEvents = function() {
    $("#Day-events-content").on("click", ".eventsToggle", function() {
        var obj = $(this).next();
        if ($(obj).hasClass("hidden")) {
            slideUpComm();
            $(obj).removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
        } else {
            $(obj).addClass("hidden").slideUp();
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to use slideUpComm as function that I include on different events but console return Uncaught ReferenceError: slideUpComm is not defined.
How I should pass function to function ? Should I use callback?

```
function dateObj() {
this.d = new Date();
this.day = this.d.getDate();
this.numDay = this.d.getDay();
this.month = parseInt(this.d.getMonth());
this.year = this.d.getFullYear();

this.slideUpComm = function (){

} 
this.showhideEvents = function() {

});
}
}
```

My Object look like above.

Comment: What is `this`, and how are you calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `slideUpComm` is a member of an object... so you need to use the object reference to invoke the method

```
//create a closure varaible to hold the reference to the instance
var self = this;
this.slideUpComm = function (){
    $("#Day-events-content p").addClass("hidden").slideUp("fast");
} 
this.showhideEvents = function() {
    $("#Day-events-content").on("click", ".eventsToggle", function() {
        var obj = $(this).next();
        if ($(obj).hasClass("hidden")) {
            //slideUpComm is a instance property so access it using the instance
            self.slideUpComm();
            $(obj).removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
        } else {
            $(obj).addClass("hidden").slideUp();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your help.I would like to ask is this way that I used it's appropriate of creating obj in JS? I mean best practice.

Answer (score 1):

slideUpComm is a function of dateObj, you can not directly invoke the function. So to invoke a function you need to create an instance of function/object

```
var a = new dataObj();
```

then you can invoke the function using

```
a.slideUpComm()
```

Comment: @arun-p-johny answer is correct, my answer was relevant when function invocation was not added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Could this not be reduced to:

```
$("<object>").slideToggle();
```

?

Comment: I think it's going to be shorter and clean.